# Why does my foreach-loop outputs only one checklistItem? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My aim is to get an array of all userChecklistItems but the loop only returns one value. I think it has something to do with the category-array but I can't find a solution...

```
private $responseJson = [];

public function getArray($user) {
    
    $responseJson['checklistItems'] = [
        ChecklistItem::CATEGORY_DAY => [],
        ChecklistItem::CATEGORY_WEEK => [],
        ChecklistItem::CATEGORY_MONTH => [],
        ChecklistItem::CATEGORY_ONE_HUNDRED_DAYS => []
    ];

    $userChecklistItems = $user->getUserChecklistItems();

    foreach($userChecklistItems as $userChecklistItem) {
        $category = $userChecklistItem->getChecklistItem()->getCategory();
        $responseJson['checklistItems'][$category] = [
            'text' => $userChecklistItem->getChecklistItem()->getText(),
            'isChecked' => $userChecklistItem->getIsChecked()
        ];
    };
    
    return $responseJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it - the newArray was missing

```
$userChecklistItems = $user->getUserChecklistItems();
    $newArray = [];

    foreach($userChecklistItems as $userChecklistItem) {
        $category = $userChecklistItem->getChecklistItem()->getCategory();
        $responseJson['checklistItems'][$category] = [
            'text' => $userChecklistItem->getChecklistItem()->getText(),
            'isChecked' => $userChecklistItem->getIsChecked()
        ];
        $newArray[] = $responseJson;
    };
    
    return $newArray;
```